# How to deserialize one JSON object for multiple classes using Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization

I am new to JSON deserialization stuffs. I have multiple classes that use the same JSON string.

The JSON looks like this:

```
"part1": {
    "part2": {
      "part3": {
        "value": [Some Integers]
      }
    }
}
```

Below is my code for deserialization:

```
public class ConfirmationDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Confirmation_A>
{
    @Override
    public Confirmation deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
        JsonNode Part3_Node = node.get("part2").get("part3");
        Integer value = Part3_Node.get("value").intValue();
        int some_class = new Some_class(value);

        #Return response class
        return new Confirmation_A(some_class);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have Confirmation_A, Confirmation_B, and Confirmation_C (they all extend the same abstract parent class), and they are all using the same JSON string and have the same parameter (some_class). It will be redundant if I create three deserializers that actually use the exactly same code and just return different response class. Is it possible to just create one deserializer for all of these three classes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could deserialize using the parents class. That way you could deserialize any class extending your parent class using inheritance.

Comment: @JakeMiller Thank you for the comment! The issue is that my parent class is an abstract class, and so it cannot be instantiated

Comment: Which JSON deserializer are you using?

Comment: @JakeMiller I am using JsonDeserializer.

Comment: If you don't mind switching to another JSON deserializer , use Jackson's `ObjectMapper`. Any time you need to parse a JSON string to a Java POJO, you simply instantiate an `ObjectMapper` and call `.readValue(String json, YourClass.class)`. So in this instance, you'd create a new object mapper, and call `mapper.readValue(jsonString, Confirmation_A.class)`. This'll save you the hassle of having to create a JsonDeserializer for each object you create. GitHub: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson and a tutorial here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html